GIT HUB PAGES :Failed to deploy on github pages
i deployed my React app using git hub pages which is showing blank screen
On inspect console it shows **failed to load resource: main.jsx **
this is github repo:repo
this is the Deploy linktext
i have tried changing the src path in index.html noting works !

Please take the [tour] and read [ask].
